# Is it Before or To?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

Is **before** or **to** more appropriate in this context?

....Considering her service as a teacher in the local university, it is fair to say she enjoys a degree of social and academic recognition within the regional community. Something that, added to the mentioned studies, increases the relevance of her work **to** the local authorities, which in turn can provide the necessary support for her to explore suitable solutions to the difficulties this region faces.

Comment: We say _relevant to_, but do you mean that her work is relevant _from the point of view_ of the local authorities? Proof-reading is beyond the scope of this forum, but I think you need to say who or what would 'receive support'.

Answer (score 1):

"the relevance of her work **before** the local authorities," would mean her work  in front of, in the presence of those authorities, such as at  a council meeting,

"the relevance of her work **to** the local authorities" would mean the relevance of her work -- all her work, or her work in general -- to the needs or purposes of the authorities. Either statement is grammatically correct, but the meaning is somewhat different.

- "**thus** receiving the support necessary "

- "**thereby** receiving the support  necessary"

These two have essentially identical meanings. "thus"  is a bit more common."thereby" is suggestive of legalese or academic writing.  Either is acceptable. It might be better to reword this part of the sentence. As it stands it is not quite clear whether it isn the woman or her work that would receive support, or perhaps the authorities who would. Nor is it clear who would be providing the support.